# Select query to get the any format of datetime value from the Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, datetime

I am using the below select query to get the details from excel sheet.

```
Select UserID,UserName,Country,State,City,DOB from [Sheet1$]
```

By default DOB(DateOfBirth) value is mm/dd/yyyy format in Excel file.
If i changed the DOB value format mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyy or d-m-yyyy (other than deafult format)in the excel.The above select query retriving the empty DOB value.

How to write the select query to get the any format of datetime values?

If there is any method similar to Cast() or Convert() in SQL,Let me know

Answer (score 0):

in order to GET universal value  - you should SET a universal value.

here is an example :

```
05/22/1978
```

there are more pattrens.

but here is a code which you might find easy to use :

```
if (value != null)
{
    if (value is double)
    {
        dt = DateTime.FromOADate((double)value);
    }
    else
    {
        DateTime.TryParse((string)value, out dt); //here you can try patterns of dd/mm/yyyy
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Don't waste your time with casts. Simply fetch the value you need, and then have String.Format display it in the format you need it to be displayed in.

Query the normal DoB value (like in your format `mm/dd/yyyy`), and where you display it, use `String.Format( {0:dd/MM/yyyy},DOB );`

Hope this helps

For instance, after you have your dataset with the results in it,

```
string DateOfBirth = String.Format ( {0:dd/MM/yyyy},<yourDataSet>.Tables[0].Rows.Field<string>(column_number));
```